# Meteor: Random 100% CPU usage at the browser

Tags: google-chrome, meteor, cpu-usage

I'm using Mac OS Yosemite with Google Chrome. Sometimes, for some random unknown reason, Chrome takes over 1 core at 100%. When I kill the process, I notice that It killed the tab in which the Meteor app was loaded. Sometimes it takes over my 4 cpu cores.

I'm using the development mode and, at least I think, I'm not doing anything to trigger it. This behaviour seems random and very hard to reproduce. I don't if it's Chrome or Meteor that cause this random behaviour.

Did someone already experienced this?

Comment: can you describe what your meteor app does? do you have large collections?

Comment: No. I suspect that this behaviour happens on the reload, hot code push, but I've no evidence of so. Try to open 3 tabs of the same app and while you develop and maybe this will happen to you.

Comment: do you have observeChanges or observe on the app?

Comment: Sounds like an infinite loop...

Comment: can you make a example on meteorpad ?

Comment: When I have experienced this it was from an infinite loop.  An autorun getting and setting a value in a loop.

Comment: @Ethann: No. dayuloli: True but this happens even with simple apps. Guidouil: As I wrote, it's very hard to replicate and I don't if this code specific.